# How to hide Items from bottom bar programmatically

Tags: java, android, bottombar

I am adding bottom bar using [This Library](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar). I want to user can enable disable item by filter which tab should be show or hide. but i can't able to hide the items programmatically. is there any way to hide the tabs programmatically.

**TABS**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tabs>
<tab
    id="@+id/facebook"
    icon="@drawable/ic_facebook_logo"
    title="facebook"
    inActiveColor="#ffffff"
    barColorWhenSelected="#3b5998"
    activeColor="#ffffff"
    />
<tab
    id="@+id/googleplus"
    icon="@drawable/ic_google"
    title="google+"
    inActiveColor="#ffffff"
    activeColor="#ffffff"
    barColorWhenSelected="#dd4b39"/>
<tab
    id="@+id/twitter"
    icon="@drawable/ic_twitter_social"
    title="twitter"
    barColorWhenSelected="#00aced"
    inActiveColor="#ffffff"

    activeColor="#ffffff"
    />
<tab
    id="@+id/instagram"
    icon="@drawable/ic_instagram_social"
    title="instagram"
    inActiveColor="#ffffff"

    activeColor="#ffffff"
    barColorWhenSelected="#cd486b"/>
<tab
    id="@+id/linkedin"
    icon="@drawable/ic_linkedin_logo"
    title="linkedin"
    inActiveColor="#ffffff"
    barColorWhenSelected="#0077b5"
    activeColor="#ffffff"
    />
</tabs>
```

**XML**

```
<com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:bb_tabXmlResource="@xml/tabs"
        app:bb_behavior="shy"
        app:bb_activeTabAlpha="1"
        app:bb_showShadow="true"
        />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just do

```
bottomBar.getTabAtPosition(x).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: Thanks but its not fully wrap can you tell me how to do it